Give a component as prop without rendering
Currently I have this situation:
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Component1 icon={<Icon color="green" />} />
    </div>
  );
}

const Component1 = ({ icon }) => {
  const data = [
    { name: "First", color: "green" },
    { name: "Second", color: "red" },
  ];

  return (
    <ul>
      {data.map((dat, index) => (
        <div key={index}>
          <li>Name: {dat.name}</li>
          <li>Icon: {icon}</li>
        </div>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
};

const Icon = ({ color }) => (
  <div style={{ backgroundColor: color, width: 20, height: 20 }} />
);

According to this code, the Icon will be always the same for each value of data.
I need to pass the Icon component to Component1 as a prop but without giving the value of the prop color there, instead, I need to use the values that comes from data. How can I do it?
The Icon component can't be modified.
I wanted to do something like this:
  {data.map((dat, index) => (
    <div key={index}>
      <li>Name: {dat.name}</li>
      <li>Icon: {<icon color={dat.color} />}</li>
    </div>
  ))}

But that won't work.

Do you have to pass the Icon to Component1?
Why not just render the <Icon color={dat.color}/> within the map?

Agreed with @CoolHandClay, why pass the Icon at all. But here's an evil way of doing it. Turn icon into a function <Component1 icon={(color) => <Icon color={color} />} />. And then map it like: <li>Icon: {icon(dat.color)}</li>

Long history. There's a circular dependency if I do that. In the example of course has no sense, but in m real case I can't do that, plus, the component can not be imported there (there are some scope restrictions, out of my control, the only way is to pass as a prop)

So instead of passing the Icon the way you are right now, you can pass the entire component in.
Within the app you change the Component1 call to
<Component1 IconComponent={Icon} />

With this the use of the Icon within the component becomes something like this
<IconComponent color={data.color} />

I am assuming this is simply an example and these are not all within the same file, if they are you can just call it directly without all of the passing around.
With this you are passing the component instead of a rendered instance of Icon.

The key here is to name the prop with an initial capital letter (as in the example here) so that it’s recognized as a component by JSX.

@TimMoore that was my whole problem, thanks
